# How to create custom binding types in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a custom class called `TimeElapsed` (which is immutable). `TimeElapsed` has a constructor that takes in a `Duration` (which is the type used in JavaFx `MediaPlayer` to keep track of time). The constructor then converts the `Duration` to a `TimeElapsed`.

The issue is that I have a function that needs to return a `TimeElapsed` `ObservableValue`. What I need is to be able to do something like this:

```
new Binding<TimeElapsed>() {

     {
          super.bind(player.duration())
     }

     @Override
     protected TimeElapsed computeValue() {
          return new TimeElapsed(player.duration());
     }
}
```

But for some reason there is no `Binding` generic, and you can only do this with `DoubleBinding` and things like that, where you compute the value but can't select the type. So, what should I do?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if [ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed>](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/ObjectBinding.html) doesn't work for you, could you explain why?  Thx

Comment: @jewelsea I was actually just about to answer my own question that I should use `ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed>`. For some reason, i wasn't able to find out that that class existed until I looked through all of related classes to `Bindings`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sample solution using an [`ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/ObjectBinding.html).

*Key method*

```
/* @return an ObjectBinding of immutable TimeElapsed objects for the player */
private ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI(
        final MediaPlayer player
    ) {
    return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
        new Callable<TimeElapsed>() {
            @Override
            public TimeElapsed call() throws Exception {
                return new TimeElapsed(player.getCurrentTime());
            }
        },
        player.currentTimeProperty()
    );
}
```

*Complete executable example*

Change the `MEDIA_PATH` in the sample to match your required media.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

/** Displays progress (time elapsed in seconds) of playing a media file. */    
public class TimeElapsedBinding extends Application {
    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = 
        "C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music\\Dillon - Thirteen Thirtyfive.mp3";

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final MediaView   mediaView    = createMediaView();
        final MediaPlayer player       = mediaView.getMediaPlayer();
        final Label       elapsedLabel = new Label();

        ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> elapsedBinding =
            createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI(player);
        StringBinding elapsedStringBinding =
            createStringBindingByBindingsAPI(elapsedBinding);

        elapsedLabel.textProperty().bind(
                elapsedStringBinding
        );

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 20px;");
        layout.getChildren().setAll(
                mediaView,
                elapsedLabel
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    /* @return an ObjectBinding of immutable TimeElapsed objects for the player */
    private ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI(
            final MediaPlayer player
        ) {
        return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
            new Callable<TimeElapsed>() {
                @Override
                public TimeElapsed call() throws Exception {
                    return new TimeElapsed(player.getCurrentTime());
                }
            },
            player.currentTimeProperty()
        );
    }

    /* @return a string binding to an ObjectBinding of immutable TimeElapsed objects */
    private StringBinding createStringBindingByBindingsAPI(
            final ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> elapsedBinding
        ) {
        return Bindings.createStringBinding(
                new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        return String.format(
                                "%.0f",
                                elapsedBinding.getValue().getElapsed()
                        );
                    }
                },
                elapsedBinding
        );
    }

    /* @Return a new MediaView from a predefined MEDIA_PATH string */
    private MediaView createMediaView() throws MalformedURLException {
        String mediaURI = new File(MEDIA_PATH).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();

        Media media = new Media(mediaURI);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        player.play();

        return mediaView;
    }

    /** immutable TimeElapsed class. */
    class TimeElapsed {
        private final double elapsed;

        TimeElapsed(Duration duration) {
            elapsed = duration.toSeconds();
        }

        public double getElapsed() {
            return elapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is provided only as a sample to fit into the question framework of using an immutable object in an ObjectBinding, rather than as the most efficient way to track the progress of playing media.

*Alternate Implementation*

Without the requirement of using an immutable object in an ObjectBinding, I would monitor the progress property of a MediaPlayer directly, similar to the code below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class MediaProgressMonitoring extends Application {
    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music\\Dillon - Thirteen Thirtyfive.mp3";

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final MediaView   mediaView = createMediaView();
        final MediaPlayer player    = mediaView.getMediaPlayer();
        final ProgressBar progress  = new ProgressBar(0);
        progress.setPrefWidth(800);

        player.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observable) ->
            progress.setProgress(
                player.getCurrentTime().toMillis() / 
                player.getTotalDuration().toMillis()
            )
        );

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 20px;");
        layout.getChildren().setAll(
                mediaView,
                progress
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private MediaView createMediaView() throws MalformedURLException {
        String mediaURI = new File(MEDIA_PATH).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();

        Media media = new Media(mediaURI);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        player.play();

        return mediaView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Since your answer implied it, is there a significantly more efficient way to track the progress? From a programming point of view this seems simplest, but if it's significantly worse than another option, I'd like to look into that.

Comment: Updated answer to add info on monitoring media playing progress directly.  The best solution to use in your situation will depend on your total system requirements.

Comment: thanks, Its also works with mac m1(silicon), Do you elaborate some codes that bindings with a progressBar and a slider ?  Because, It seems a bug in mac m1 for progressbar and slider. I also try your github Codes, but no luck : https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1446612

Comment: @NoorHossain ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @jewelsea, thanks for quick reply, here is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71682501/javafx-media-player-binding-progress-bar-with-media-player-mac-m1-silicon