# JavaFX ObjectBinding doesn't trigger computeValue, the bound property doesn't change

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I'm trying to bind the color(fill) that is `ObjectProperty<Paint> (fillProperty)` of a JavaFX Circle Shape. For that, I am using a low level ObjectBinding. I want to use the `Color.hsb()` to create a new color using the hue value which will be scaled according to the desiredSpeedProperty which is stored in the Car class, and the actual speed of the car.

I have tried multiple ways of binding the speed value of the Car including DoubleBinding to store the speed value. I have also explicitly tried to `getFill()` of the Circle shape as I was assuming my problem was caused by the laziness of Java. But still no success.

```java
Circle carShape  = new Circle();
ObjectBinding<Paint> colorObjectBinding = new ObjectBinding<Paint>() {
            {
                super.bind(car.getSpeed().getXProperty(),car.getSpeed().getYProperty(),car.getParameters().desiredSpeedProperty());
            }
            @Override
            protected Paint computeValue() {
                double speedX = car.getSpeed().getX();
                double speedY = car.getSpeed().getY();
                Color color = Color.hsb(Math.sqrt(speedX*speedX+speedY*speedY)*110/car.getParameters().getDesiredSpeed(),0.94,0.94,0.94);
                return color;
            }
        };
        carShape.fillProperty().bind(colorObjectBinding);
```

`car.speed` is of type `Vector2D` which uses `DoubleProperty` to store the x and y value of a Vector.

```java
public class Vector2D implements Iterable<DoubleProperty>{

    private DoubleProperty xProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private DoubleProperty yProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    public DoubleProperty getXProperty() { return xProperty; }
    public DoubleProperty getYProperty() { return yProperty; }

    public double getX() { return xProperty.getValue(); }
    public double getY() { return yProperty.getValue(); }
```

The `desiredSpeed` is also a `DoubleProperty`

```java
private DoubleProperty desiredSpeed = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

public double getDesiredSpeed() { return desiredSpeed.get(); }
```

I want the color of the car to change accordingly with the change of speed. But the Circles are colored just once upon creation with the color Red `(0xf00e0ef0)` (which I suspect is because the initial speed is zero thus giving hue = 0 for which the color is red)

**Update**

I have found my mistake, the problem was in the method `car.getSpeed()`

```java
public Vector2D getSpeed() { return new Vector2D(speed);  }
```

Which as you can see is returning a copy of the speed object, which is then bound, which is of course non-sense since the copy will most likely never be changed or used again. :( :0

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. There could be an issue with the implementations of the properties; It would also be possible that `Car.speed` and `Car.parameters` are properties of their own in which case the binding does not catch changes of those. BTW: the naming convention of the `x` and `y` property getters are wrong: they should simply be `xProperty` and `yProperty` instead of `get...`

Comment: @fabain I tried to provide more information concerning what you mentioned. As you see speed values are a `DoubleProperty` as well as the `desiredSpeed` , I don't understand why that would be a problem since in order to bind anything they have to be properties and not just double values. In terms of naming I'm fully aware now but thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: The info is still insufficient: How do you update the speed? Do you update the speed object itself, replace the speed object? Can this property be modified? Same for `parameters`? BTW: I recommend using `get` instead of `getValue` in `getY` ect. Otherwise the value is autoboxed to get a `Double` to return for `getValue` and then unboxed to get a primitive `double`. You can avoid the creation of this object by using the method of `DoubleProperty` returning a primitive value...

Comment: @fabian Thanks for the advice will definitely change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working minimal, complete, verifiable example of how i finally managed to `bind` the `fillProperty` of the `Circle` shape. The timeline is just a way to check if color change is responding.

```java
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import tomek.szypula.math.Vector2D;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class ColorBindingTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    final private double maxSpeed = 10;
    final private double maxColor = 110; //Green

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene theScene = new Scene( root,1100, 800 );
        primaryStage.setTitle("ColorBindingTest");
        primaryStage.setScene(theScene);

        Circle carShape  = new Circle();
        Vector2D speed = new Vector2D();

        carShape.setCenterX(100);
        carShape.setCenterY(100);
        carShape.setRadius(10);

        root.getChildren().add(carShape);

        ObjectBinding<Color> colorObjectBinding1 = Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                new Callable<Color>() {
                    @Override
                    public Color call() throws Exception {
                        double speedX = speed.getX();
                        double speedY = speed.getY();
                        Color color = Color.hsb(Math.sqrt(speedX*speedX+speedY*speedY)*maxColor/maxSpeed,0.94,0.94,0.94);
                        return color;
                    }
                },speed.getXProperty(),speed.getYProperty()
        );
        carShape.fillProperty().bind(colorObjectBinding1);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(200),
                ae -> {
                    speed.setX(Math.random()*maxSpeed);
                }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and a minimal version of the `Vector2D` class, which could as well be just replaced with a `DoubleProperty`

```java
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Vector2D {

    private DoubleProperty xProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private DoubleProperty yProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    public Vector2D(double x, double y) {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public Vector2D(final Vector2D v) {
        this(v.getX(), v.getY());
    }

    public Vector2D(){this(0,0); }

    public double getX() {
        return xProperty.getValue();
    }

    public void setX(double x) {  this.xProperty.setValue(x);   }

    public double getY() {
        return yProperty.getValue();
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.yProperty.setValue(y);
    }

    public void setVector(Vector2D vector2D) {
        setY(vector2D.getY());
        setX(vector2D.getX());
    }

    public DoubleProperty getXProperty() {
        return xProperty;
    }
    public DoubleProperty getYProperty() {
        return yProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create custom bindings is by using the utility of the `Bindings` class (in your case `Bindings#createObjectBinding()`). For example like:

```
Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    double speedX = car.getSpeed().getX();
    double speedY = car.getSpeed().getY();
    Color color = Color.hsb(Math.sqrt(speedX*speedX+speedY*speedY)*110/car.getParameters().getDesiredSpeed(),0.94,0.94,0.94);
    return color;
}, car.getSpeed().getXProperty(),car.getSpeed().getYProperty(),car.getParameters().desiredSpeedProperty()) ;
```

Also, there are simular questions like this as well which you might find answers. 
[How to create custom binding types in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213999/how-to-create-custom-binding-types-in-javafx)

Comment: I tried using your code snippet, unfortunately, something is not quite right in terms of syntax, I changed it a little based on the answer you submitted and still no change, it still has no effect. And I can't seem to post in a comment a code example :/

Comment: @TomekSzypuła What you need to do is edit your question and post a [mcve] as you were asked, that will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: If the above code snippet is not working, you are propably doing something else wrong. As requested multiple times, post a small test class (also called Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) so we can help you find that problem.