# JavaFX Media Player - Binding Progress bar with Media Player (Mac m1 Silicon)

Tags: macos, javafx, binding, apple-m1

I want to update Progress Bar with Media Player Playing. But, after start playing my progressBar fill 100% within one second while the media is 15 seconds - 5 minutes long.  I can't figure out the cause.

My codes are as follows:

```
public static ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();

ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> elapsedBinding =createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI(player);
DoubleBinding elapsedDoubleBinding =createDoubleBindingByBindingsAPI(elapsedBinding);

progress.progressProperty().bind(elapsedDoubleBinding);
```

And The methods are :

```
    public static @NotNull ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI(
            final @NotNull MediaPlayer player
    ) {
        return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                new Callable<TimeElapsed>() {
                    @Override
                    public TimeElapsed call() throws Exception {
                        return new TimeElapsed(player.getCurrentTime());
                    }
                },
                player.currentTimeProperty()
        );
    }



public static @NotNull DoubleBinding createDoubleBindingByBindingsAPI(
            final ObjectBinding<TimeElapsed> elapsedBinding
    ) {
        return Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                new Callable<Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Double call() throws Exception {

                        
                        return  elapsedBinding.getValue().getElapsed();

                    }
                },
                elapsedBinding
        );
    }
```

And the TimeElapsed class :

```
static class TimeElapsed {
        private final double elapsed;

        TimeElapsed(@NotNull Duration duration) {
          
            elapsed = duration.toSeconds();
        }

        public double getElapsed() {
            return elapsed;
        }
    }
```

So, what's the code changes that 1)  update the progressBar with Playing, and 2) seek the song with progress bar clicked or dragged?

Comment: Progress has to be between 0 and 1, so you need the elapsed seconds divided by the total seconds from the media player

Comment: don't use static scope

Comment: @James_D, I have tried that, but every songs length return value was same and the value was not so suitable as the song length, that means actual length value not supplied or permitted.

Answer (score 0):

The progress of a `ProgressBar` should be, when determinate, between the values of `0.0` and `1.0` (inclusive). This means you should be dividing the current time by the total duration to get the progress and bind the progress property of the bar to that value. Note that the duration of a `Media` is observable and is pretty much guaranteed to be set some time *after* it was instantiated.

As for being able to seek when the progress bar is clicked or dragged, the simplest way—which is what I show in the example below—is to add a `MOUSE_CLICKED` and a `MOUSE_DRAGGED` handler to the progress bar, determine the ratio between the mouse's `x` position and the bar's width, and then seek the calculated time. Unfortunately, this setup may not *exactly* match up with the visuals of the progress bar because the actual "bar" is smaller than the entire space taken up by the node (at least with default styling). You would probably have to create your own control if you want "pixel perfect" behavior.

---

Here is a minimal example demonstrating what's discussed above:

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var mediaView = new MediaView();

    var progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    StackPane.setAlignment(progressBar, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    StackPane.setMargin(progressBar, new Insets(10));

    var root = new StackPane(mediaView, progressBar);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 650));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Video Progress Demo");
    primaryStage.show();

    chooseMediaFile(primaryStage)
        .ifPresentOrElse(
            uri -> {
              var media = new Media(uri);
              var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
              mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
              mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

              bindProgress(mediaPlayer, progressBar);
              addSeekBehavior(mediaPlayer, progressBar);
            },
            Platform::exit);
  }

  private void bindProgress(MediaPlayer player, ProgressBar bar) {
    var binding =
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
            () -> {
              var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
              var duration = player.getMedia().getDuration();
              if (isValidDuration(currentTime) && isValidDuration(duration)) {
                return currentTime.toMillis() / duration.toMillis();
              }
              return ProgressBar.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS;
            },
            player.currentTimeProperty(),
            player.getMedia().durationProperty());
    bar.progressProperty().bind(binding);
  }

  private void addSeekBehavior(MediaPlayer player, ProgressBar bar) {
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClickAndOnDragHandler =
        e -> {
          var duration = player.getMedia().getDuration();
          if (isValidDuration(duration)) {
            var seekTime = duration.multiply(e.getX() / bar.getWidth());
            player.seek(seekTime);
            e.consume();
          }
        };
    bar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, onClickAndOnDragHandler);
    bar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, onClickAndOnDragHandler);
  }

  private boolean isValidDuration(Duration d) {
    return d != null && !d.isIndefinite() && !d.isUnknown();
  }

  private Optional<String> chooseMediaFile(Stage owner) {
    var chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser
        .getExtensionFilters()
        .add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Media Files", "*.mp4", "*.mp3", "*.wav"));
    var file = chooser.showOpenDialog(owner);
    return Optional.ofNullable(file).map(f -> f.toPath().toUri().toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I get duration for every song :  9.739150367346899E7 ms.   while check with System.out.println("Duration : "+duration); In your code : var duration = player.getMedia().getDuration();  So, ProgressBar show nothing.  Is this behaviour for Mac M1 (silicon) ? what can I do ?

Comment: If these are media files you know for sure report the correct duration (e.g., in other applications, or other operating systems), then it might be a bug with JavaFX. I believe there were quite a few bugs with M1 systems when support was first added, so first make sure you're using the latest version of JavaFX (as of writing this comment, the latest version is 18). If the problem persists on the latest version, and you can create a [mre] demonstrating the problem, then I suggest [submitting a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: thanks, I have used latest version, even I have taken eyes on platform. So, I think it is bug. But I am not familiar with submitting bug report. Anyway, I will try, Insha Allah.